# How to set the state of a variable before the onStart() function is called - Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

So I am trying to check whether or not the user is logged in using Firebase, and then say whether or not that user is logged in using a `Text()` object. I am trying to achieve that by setting the state of that Text object. I am getting an error though that is caused by the `setContent{}` function being called after the onStart(), where I need the text state, function which is where all of my state variables are initialized. So my question is there a way that I can initialize a state before the onStart() function is called?

Code:

```
package com.example.firebaseauthenticationapp

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import com.example.firebaseauthenticationapp.ui.theme.FireBaseAuthenticationAppTheme
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.tasks.await
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    lateinit var emailRegister: MutableState<String>
    lateinit var passwordRegister: MutableState<String>
    lateinit var emailLogin: MutableState<String>
    lateinit var passwordLogin: MutableState<String>
    lateinit var isLoggedIn: MutableState<String>
    lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        setContent {
            isLoggedIn = remember{ mutableStateOf("")}
            emailRegister = remember{mutableStateOf("")}
            passwordRegister = remember{mutableStateOf("")}
            emailLogin = remember{mutableStateOf("")}
            passwordLogin = remember{mutableStateOf("")}


            Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center, horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally, modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(5.dp)
            ){
                Header("Register")
                OutlinedTextFields(textState = emailRegister, hint = "Enter E-Mail")
                OutlinedTextFields(textState = passwordRegister, hint = "Enter Password")
                Button(onClick = {registerUser()}, modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 4.dp, bottom = 4.dp)){Text("REGISTER")}
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 60.dp))
                Header("Login")
                OutlinedTextFields(textState = emailLogin, hint = "Enter E-Mail")
                OutlinedTextFields(textState = passwordLogin, hint = "Enter Password")
                Button(onClick = {loginUser()}, modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 4.dp, bottom = 4.dp)){Text("LOGIN")}
                Header(isLoggedIn.value)
            }
        }
    }
    private fun registerUser(){
        if(emailRegister.value.isNotEmpty() && passwordRegister.value.isNotEmpty()){
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch{
                try{
                    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailRegister.value, passwordRegister.value).await()
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                        checkLoggedInState()
                    }
                } catch(e: Exception){
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    override fun onStart(){
        super.onStart()
        checkLoggedInState()
    }


    private fun loginUser(){
        if(emailLogin.value.isNotEmpty() && passwordLogin.value.isNotEmpty()){
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch{
                try{
                    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailLogin.value, passwordLogin.value).await()
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                        checkLoggedInState()
                    }
                } catch(e: Exception){
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private fun checkLoggedInState(){
        if(auth.currentUser == null){
            isLoggedIn.value = "You are not logged in"
        } else{
            isLoggedIn.value = "You are logged in!"
        }
    }


}





@Composable
fun Header(text: String){
    Text(text, fontSize = 20.sp, modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 4.dp, bottom = 4.dp))
}
@Composable
fun OutlinedTextFields(textState: MutableState<String>, hint: String){
   OutlinedTextField(value = textState.value, onValueChange = {textState.value = it}, label = {Text(text = hint)}, modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 4.dp, bottom = 4.dp))
}
```

```
Error being run:
2021-08-05 20:02:08.161 10690-10690/com.example.firebaseauthenticationapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.firebaseauthenticationapp, PID: 10690
    kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property isLoggedIn has not been initialized
        at com.example.firebaseauthenticationapp.MainActivity.isLoggedIn(MainActivity.kt:31)
        at com.example.firebaseauthenticationapp.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.kt:81)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1435)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8222)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3818)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Comment: Display an indetermined progress indicator until you know the logged in state.

Comment: Please highlight the lines 31, and 81, as pointed out by the logs. Highlight others too if more are there. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `lateinit` value was initialized like this: `if (::isLoggedIn.isInitialized)`

But generally speaking, such login should be inside a [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodel-state). `remember` variables shouldn't leak out of the view.

Inside `setContent` you should only initialize something like `TopView()` composable, also declare theme and provide local compose values using `CompositionLocalProvider`. If you had to place more logic there, you're probably doing something wrong.